# req params return sundefined not sure why

Tags: express, axios, parameters, router

For some reason, const brand = req.params.brand is returning undefined. The route in questions is /shop/:brand and it should be returning whatever :brand is

```js
import express from "express";
import Product from "../models/Product.js";
const productRoutes = express.Router();

const getProducts = async (req, res) => {
  const brand = req.params.brand;
  console.log(brand)
  let products;

  if (brand) {
    products = await Product.find({ brand });
  } else {
    products = await Product.find({});
  }
  res.json(products);
};

productRoutes.route("/").get(getProducts);
productRoutes.route("/shop/:brand").get(getProducts);

export default productRoutes;
```

Here is my productActions file

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { setProducts, setLoading, setError } from "../slices/products";

export const getProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setLoading(true));
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/products");
    dispatch(setProducts(data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(
      setError(
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message
          ? error.message
          : "An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later."
      )
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: What is the brand that you're trying to pass? Do you mean something like `axios.get("/api/products/some-brand-here")`?

Comment: Yes that’s what im trying to do. I want to pull from redux on the brands that match the name of the param. So that shop/apple only shows apple products, and so on

Comment: Well, it's not showing a brand on the backend because you didn't include one when sending. On the frontend, you need to include a brand like I showed.

Comment: Oh ok so on the frontend id also need to make an axios call like /api/products/shop/${brand} ?

Comment: Yes. What data would you receive on the backend otherwise? (Sorry, I missed `shop` in my original comment).